I can't create column created_at
I used List<> to create an additional column created_at but it didn't work.
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
name = "follows",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following_user_id")
)
@Column(name = "created_at")
private List<Users> followingUser;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
  createAt = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
}

when I used Map<> it worked but it had a primary key
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
name = "follows",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following_user_id")
)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "create_at")
private Map<Timestamp, Users> followingUser;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
   createAt = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
}


"it didn't work" What happened?

Since it's @ManyToMany relations it will create a new table with two columns(user_id, following_user_id). @Column(name="created_at) only works when you define one column in the table.
for more refer  Many to Many relation
